# How do I ensure a Puppet exec resource always includes `set -o pipefail`?

Tags: sh, puppet

In a particular project, I have a lot of Puppet `exec` resources with pipes. This seems to work just fine.

```
exec { 'foobar': 
  command => 'foo | bar',
}
```

However, there are occasions where `foo` fails. The default behavior is to report the exit code only for the last command in the pipeline. I can fix this manually.

```
exec { 'foobar': 
  command  => 'set -o pipefail; foo | bar',
  provider => shell,
}
```

But, I want to make sure this happens in all these cases automatically. I'd like to avoid manual find/replace and auditing all uses of `exec`.

- Am I missing some useful attribute?
- Is there a wrapper I can use?
- Am I, unfortunately, looking at a custom resource?

Comment: Probably not: even a macro would not help here. Don't know. Probably yes, if by custom resource you mean custom parser function and/or custom type; a custom define would very likely not help you here.

Answer (score 1):

> - Am I missing some useful attribute?

No, `Exec` has no attribute that would automatically prepend additional code to the command.

> - Is there a wrapper I can use?

I'm not confident I understand what you mean by a "wrapper", but do see below.

> - Am I, unfortunately, looking at a custom resource?

If you're asking whether you need to implement a native custom type, then surely not.  You can undoubtedly address this problem with a (DSL-level) defined type, though you will need to adjust all your `Exec` declarations to be declarations of the defined type instead.  This may be what you mean by a "wrapper" -- I'm fairly sure there's no existing one for your particular purpose, but it shouldn't be hard to create one:

```
define mymodule::exec (
  command     => $title,
  creates     => 'NOT SET',
  cwd         => 'NOT SET',
  # ... all other regular parameters ...
) {
  $real_provider = $provider ? { 'NOT SET' => 'shell', default => $provider }
  if $real_provider == 'shell' {
    $real_command = "set -o pipefail; $command"
  } else {
    warning('Non-shell command declared via mymodule::exec')
    $real_command = $command
  }

  exec { $title:
    command  => $real_command,
    provider => $real_provider,
    creates  => $creates ? { 'NOT SET' => undef, default => $creates },
    cwd      => $cwd ? { 'NOT SET' => undef, default => $cwd },
    # ... all remaining regular parameters ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Why have all those ternaries instead of using the class parameter default values directly? e.g. `mymodule::exec (provider     => 'NOT SET')` and `$real_provider = $provider ? { 'NOT SET' => 'shell', default => $provider }` instead of `mymodule::exec (provider     => 'shell')`

Comment: @MattSchuchard, the point is twofold: (1) you need to provide default values for the parameters to avoid forcing the user to provide explicit values, but (2) where the user in fact does not provide a value, you want to express that in the resource declaration inside by passing `undef`.  This is a pretty classic pattern for optional parameters.

Comment: I still don't see why the ternaries cannot be removed and the values directly provided as defaults in the class parameter arguments, because both seem functionally isomorphic to me, but I guess we just have different opinions on code style.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, this is a question of function, not style.  Where the parameter list does not specify a default value for a given parameter, the user is obligated to provide a value explicitly.  We (I) want to avoid this for parameters that are not mandatory on the underlying `Exec`, which is all of them.  But when those default values are actually taken (because the user did not explicitly specify a value) we need to translate *back* to no value being specified, which the selectors accomplish by evaluating to `undef` in that case.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I think you have an interesting question that you should post as such and earn some rep!